# What photographic effects can give the feeling of escapism and anxiety?

Tags: post-processing, color, composition, color-filters, mood

I need to create a photograph that gives the feeling of escapism and anxiety. What kind of techniques can I use — especially in post-processing — to create this mood.

Comment: I've removed some tags about color and white balance. If you have ideas about how color might aid in what you're looking for, please add that to the question.

Comment: It would also help a little more if you could describe what these things mean to you — is it one shared emotion with both feelings, or two separate things which you want combined at once, or something else? Do you mean "escapism" in the [standard sense](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/escapism) of "fantasy to retreat from reality", or do you mean "scared and wanting to run away" (which seems like it might pair with "anxiety" more.

Comment: Also, your question seemed to focus on finding a magical effect you could apply to create this feeling. Art doesn't _really_ work that way, and I'd encourage you to be open to _composition_ and story-building techniques rather than just focusing on applying an effect.

Comment: for anxiety i need to describe the details of it on any person ,

Comment: Is this a school assignment? (Not that it's a problem if it is — it's just better if you say!) By "on any person", do you mean that you are making a portrait?

Comment: escapism for me is when you escape from reality ... and i think there is a link between anxiety and depression and in the end it will lead to escapism , so i need to bulid a story about this .. i have many ideas but i need to use color to create the feeling of this . thanks

Comment: There is definitely a link. Thanks for clarifying; I just wasn't sure.

Comment: I think creating a feeling of escapism, anxiety, or a link between the two will be highly dependant on the content: subject, composition. For example a person, posed, the use of an expanse of negative space or elements that represent something to be anxious about. I'm not sure what you mean by "effects" but if you mean software filters, these might enhance a feeling. The use of light, shadow, and color an affect feelings. For example, dark blue shadows might be something you like; but this is a broad question so I think I can only give you more to think about

Comment: i mean by effect something like : in summer , we shot in worm colors to creative the effect of high temperature  , in winter we shot in cold colors that gives the cold effect

Comment: So, you _really_ want something about color? That's an okay _question_, although I'm not so sure the answer will be satisfying.

Comment: I'll try shooting through an opened end Kaleidoscope with a Tele zoom lens. Maybe adding an ND filter to allow enough time for zooming while shooting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were me, I'd probably go with either a lack of color or at least desaturated colors for the anxiety/depression side. There is [some evidence](https://psychcentral.com/news/2010/07/21/decreased-perception-of-color-in-depression/15826.html) that depressed people have poorer perception of contrast, which would lead to things seeming closer to gray. I even saw a documentary once about a woman suffering from depression and going through brain surgery to treat it. She had to be kept awake during the procedure, and at one point she expressed surprise because she suddenly started to perceive color again and hadn't realized that she had lost it until that point.

While anxiety and depression are not the same, they are related. I think of anxiety as being more dark and being represented by black or nearly black colors.

For escapism, I tend to think of the fantastical worlds of movies and TV shows. And when we're talking about colors, they're always lush, saturated colors. Even Mordor from The Lord of the Rings trilogy is full of bright fiery saturated reds, yellows, and oranges.

So if you're only using colors to represent these concepts, I'd go for unsaturated/dark on the anxiety side and bright/vibrant/saturated on the escapism side.